# Не изменяется глобальная переменная PHP

Tags: php

Подскажите, почему глобальная переменная **a** не изменяется, и можно ли как-то изменить ее в данной конструкции, когда вызов идет внутри анонимной функции.

```
$a = 1;

$b = function() use ($a) {  

    function c()
    {
        global $a;
        $a++;
    }

    echo($a . '</br>');
    c();
    echo($a . '</br>');
};

$b();
```

Comment: Думаю, функция $b получает за счет use локальную копию глобальной переменной. И echo выводит именно ее. А вот `c()` видит настоящую глобальную `$a`. Что видно если сделать echo внутри `c()`

Comment: https://ideone.com/5Xryte

Comment: Вот оно как, интересно. Я почему-то думал, что переменные из секции `use` тоже глобальные. А можно как то из `c()` получить доступ к локальной копии переменной `$a` функции `$b()`?

Comment: Использование `global` признак плохого тона как и оператора `goto`. Лучшая практика - это прокидывание объектов через аргументы функции/метода.

Comment: 1. Не путайте глобальные (или суперглобальные) переменные типа $GLOBALS и внутрифайловые (контекстные). 2. Для изменения переменной внутри, передавайте её по ссылке, используя &

Answer (score 4, accepted):

вы создаете анонимную функцию и наследуете в ней переменную из глобальной области. В вашем случае, когда вы ее пытаетесь изменить, создается копия. Чтобы изменить оригинал наследовать надо по ссылке.

```
$b = function() use (&$a) {
```

апд.
вообще  дело выглядит несколько иначе. функция `c` в реальности изменяет значение глобальной `$a`. Вы можете в этом убедиться, если вызовите как и ранее свою `$b()` а потом следом `c()` (вы объявляете ее глобально во время вызова анонимки). Вы увидите, что будет выведено `1,1,3`.
А вот `echo $a` у вас выводит захваченную копию по значению, поэтому она не видит изменений. Так что в данном конкретном случае, чтобы видеть изменения надо наследовать ее по ссылке. Повторюсь "чтобы видеть", а не "чтобы менять", ибо все меняется.

Comment: еще кстати говоря, повторный вызов `$b()` приведет к ошибке, что `c` уже определена.